# Suspicious Request at the contact form really necessary?

Tags: discussion

A few minutes ago I tried a couple of times to fill out the contact form to get some support on an issue.

A couple of times it ended up saying

> "Suspicous Request - Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Stack Overflow, please return to the previous page and try again"

Suddenly it worked and I still don't know why.

So my questions are:
Wouldn't it be great to give the (help seeking) user a bit more information why the software thinks the contact form content is suspicious and what to change so it isn't?

Isn't that a bit over engineered and should be disabled at all? I mean that people looking for help shouldn't be tortured with guessing why they can't ask the official support team a simple question using the official support contact form.

Update:
Through the comments we figured out that the possible reason could have been multiple open tabs for stackexchange.

So let me ask in more detail: is it really a good idea to prevent people frombwriting support tickets because they have multiple tabs open? E.g. one tab for writing the ticket and another for copy/pasting user info?
Only saying: you evil user did something suspicous

Instead of: hey, close the other tab and you are good to go

Comment: My main guess, the "suspicious" was "a couple of times"? Because the way it's phrased now I read it as you hammered the button and after a while it said "no"...

Comment: You can get "Suspicious Request" if you have multiple tabs open.  The system sees you try to do more than one action in quick succession.  It is checking you aren't a bot.

Comment: Wait, there's a contact form?

Comment: @CodeCaster There's [a contact link](//stackoverflow.com/contact) at the bottom of every page.

Comment: Yes, but that would allow you to ask your suspicious questions, Mr. Suspicious Guy.

Comment: Well, if multiple open tabs are a problem that was the reason why it did not work and then suddenly worked. And no, I didn't hammer the button. I am a patient surfer.

Comment: Multiple tabs, @Chenmunka? I should be hitting this daily then; I have 10+ SE tabs open usually. No, I don't believe that's it -- more likely, something similar to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170923) is occurring.

Comment: Is there something in the ticket body that looks like you are trying to submit a cross site attack script?

Comment: No suspicious content if you ask me. It was just a simple text explaining why I lost access to my old account (when OpenID closed the doors) and two links to my profiles. As well as the friendly question to merge them.